# Looking for YOY YTD formula that works with fiscal years in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am looking for YOY YTD formula that works with fiscal years in tableau.

Method 1 appears to work here: https://resources.useready.com/blog/ytd-cy-vs-py-in-tableau-2-methods/ but does not work for Fiscal years.
the current year filter starts at Jan.
Is there anyway to adjust method 1 to work with fiscal years?
Note: i tried default properties-> fiscal year start to July and that did not work

See "goal in tableau screenshot below"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, assuming you computed what you're showing in Tableau
and didn't just mock it up in Excel.

If you don't have one,  create a calculated field "FY-Number" where
January -> 1,  Feb -> 2, etc.  You're already sorting in that order
so maybe you already have such a field.

Assuming your "average" is a "total"  ( using AVERAGE ),
all you need now is a filter to select FY-Number < 7.
Which you COULD do manually.
But if you want this to be automatic, and always total down to the most recent month, you could do the following. There may be better ways but this works.

And I have a hierarchy of FY-number and Fiscal-Month-number for generating the grid.

Compute a running number which we can maximize, a sequential number crossing all years, for the month.  I used formula for  FMRun to be

```
[FY num]*12 + [FM num]
```

which has a max of 270 for December 2021.   Tableau can find the max.
Next, invert that, basically, to find the max month number.

FMInvert formula:

```
{FIXED :(MAX([FMRun])/12 - FLOOR(max([FMRun])/12))*12}
```

which has a value of 6 for the data given.

Finally, filter on that with this filter I called whatmax, which we want true:

```
if  [FM num]   <= [FMinvert] then TRUE
else FALSE
END
```

And voila, you're done.

Here's the workbook.
https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/wade.schuette/viz/YOY-YTD-answer/Dashboard1?publish=yes